# ListView with ToggleButtons updating DataBase

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

i need your help, i created a custom adapter for a ListView in order to show a TextView and a ToggleButton for each record in the db. In the overrided getView method i added the values like this:

```
public class ListaUbicaciones extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ManejadorBD bd;
private List<Ubicacion> list = new ArrayList<Ubicacion>();
private Context context;

public ListaUbicaciones(List<Ubicacion> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return list.get(position).getID();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ubicacion, null);
    }
    final Ubicacion  ub= list.get(position);
    TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.titUbicacion);
    listItemText.setText(ub.getTitulo());

    ToggleButton btnToggle = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnToggle);
    final int activo = ub.getActivo();
    if (activo == 1){
        btnToggle.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        btnToggle.setChecked(false);
    }
    btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                bd.actualizarEstado(ub,1);
            }else{
                bd.actualizarEstado(ub,0);
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

The method actualizarEstado is this:

```
public void actualizarEstado(Ubicacion ub, int estado){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ACTIVO, estado);

    db.update(TABLE_LOCATIONS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ub.getID())});
}
```

So the problem is that whenever i click the toggle button and change from true to false or vice versa my app crashes and it is because the list.get(position) is null at the time that updateStatus use it as a parameter, i dont really know why, i have searched a lot in the forum but i cant find any solution u.u

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You app crashes because you create empty `ArrayList`:

```
List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

And try to get the item from it.

UPDATE:

When you click the button, `ub` variable is recycled by gc) to store it use tag:

```
btnToggle.setTag(ub);
btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Ubicacion  ubFromTag = buttonView.getTag();
            if(ubFromTag == null) return;
            if (isChecked){
                bd.actualizarEstado(ubFromTag,1);
            }else{
                bd.actualizarEstado(ubFromTag,0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry i forgot to put that part, I fill the list with all the records on the db with a method. I don't have any problem on filling the list and showing the list view correctly, the only problem I got is when I click the togglebutton and try to changet the value of "active" in the db

Comment: added the full adapters code, please take a look at it

Comment: Thanks anil, i will try this ASAP and post the results

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work anil, after doing some tests and debugging i realized that im so stupid -_- i forgot to initialize the object for the DB, i just had private ManejadorBD bd;..........omg.
Thank you anyway anil C:

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @anil, your List is empty.

But that is just one of the problems.
The right way to send your items to adapter is when you are calling a new adapter object.

You see, ListView items draws items on demand as scroll progresses. The getView() method is called whenever the ListView (or another classes that uses this adapter) needs a new View for an item in the list.

Just pass a list of items through the constructor and keep it.

Comment: I do that too Lucas in the constructor I have this.list=list; and the parameters are the list that I'm using, sorry for not putting that, I supposed that it wasn't needed

Comment: Hmmm.. Try this: Create a final variable like "final Point item = list.get(position)" and use this variable instead grabbing from the list in your if/else and in your listener

Comment: tried it and didn't work u.u check out the code again, i put the complete adapters view